# merge conflict In ADO Repo

Tags: azure-devops

Merge request in ADO repo is only showing the message **"there are conflict"** but it is not showing the **file and lines number**, where conflict happened.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you have information about merge conflict you should solve it on your machine and push it to your branch. This is why you don't have conflict details.

You can also try to use this [extension - Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab)